# How to do nfIF with a boolean result with 3 condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the same HTML code and I need to show it according of my condition

I've trying using ngIF but I need to repeat the HTML 3 times.

```js
<div *ngIf="data.dataUm"><dt>Data:</dt><dd>{{data.dataImplementacao|DateMoment}}</dd></
div>
<div *ngIf="data.dataDois"><dt>Data:</dt><dd>{{data.dataImplementacao|DateMoment}}</dd></
div>
<div *ngIf="data.dataTres"><dt>Data:</dt><dd>{{data.dataImplementacao|DateMoment}}</dd></
div>
```

so How can I use some condition to not repeat the same HTML?

Comment: Can you not stick an or `||` in there and have a single statement?

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML looks very repetitive. You can combine your HTML into a single snippet and use or `||` in your `*ngIf`. It will be the same result:

```
<div *ngIf="data.dataUm || data.dataDois || data.dataTres">
    <dt>Data:</dt>
    <dd>{{data.dataImplementacao|DateMoment}}</dd>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one statement and use `&&` to separate the three conditions if you want it to fire when all conditions are true, or use `||` if you want it to fire if one of the conditions is true.

The difference with these statements compared to your current code is that it will fire only once when the conditions are met. With your code it will fire each time one of the conditions are.